# How to display Toolbar in my Application?

Tags: android

I'm building an app with Android Studio, but I can't to display ToolBar.
This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
            android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.main.nuovoOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.creaOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.mainOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.viewOrdine"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.setting.setting"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.articoli.viewArticoli"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.mainClienti"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.viewClienti"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.infoCliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.operazioniCliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.operazioniClienteDettaglio"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I display ToolBar ?

> EDIT
>   This is the activity main

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/articoli"
                android:onClick="visualizzaArticoli"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Articoli"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/order"
                android:onClick="creaOrdine"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ordini"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/customer"
                android:onClick="viewClienti"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cliente"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sincronizza"
                android:onClick="allineaDatase"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/allinea_database"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/setting"
                android:onClick="setting"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/impostazioni"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

package com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.main;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.R;
import com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.beans.Program;
import com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.connection.MyDatabase;
import com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.utility.SyncDati;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public MyDatabase db;
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    public String url="";
    private static final Intent SCAN_INTENT = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
        //  layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(Color.BLUE));

        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(SCAN_INTENT, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
        //      if(resolveInfo==null) {
        //          ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.scanButton)).setEnabled(false);
        //          ((TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.scanResult)).setText("Non hai installato nessuna applicazione per effettuare lo scan!!!\nScaricala qui: http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.google.zxing.client.android");
        //      }

    }

    public void onScan(View view) {
        startActivityForResult(SCAN_INTENT, 0);
    }

    private void apriConnessioneDB(){
        db=new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        db.open();  //apriamo il db
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void visualizzaArticoli(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.articoli.viewArticoli.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void viewClienti(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.mainClienti.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void creaOrdine(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.mainOrdine.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void setting(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.setting.setting.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void allineaDatase(View view){
        try{

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You will need to post more information, like your mainActivity.xml and java file. This is where you would initialize your toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

```
Use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"`enter code here`
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Toolbar title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="visualizzaArticoli"
              />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="Articoli" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="creaOrdine"
               />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="viewClienti"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="allineaDatase"
               />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="setting"
               />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    enter code here

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `AppTheme` in `styles.xml` has `Theme` with `NoActionbar` like

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Make it to below

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```